# Apache Tuning for 512GB RAM

Tags: mysql, php, apache2, performance-tuning

### Use Case:

#### API Server Cluster Optimized for JSON Data Submission

I have a distributed application sending info to API servers that are slaves of a MySQL 8 master. Applications do full initial sync (~100,000 records in batches of 500) followed by incremental syncs every 5 minutes.

I have 3 Dell R620 servers with 512GB RAM, 5 SSD in RAID 6 that are acting as web servers. I have dedicated one to being a master MySQL using the following config:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
# GENERAL #
pid-file                   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/
bind-address=*

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover-options         = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
#skip-grant-tables

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
binlog_expire_logs_seconds     = 2000
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 10000
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096
#
## INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 360G
#
## LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#

## REPLICATION ##
slave-parallel-workers=10
slave-parallel-type = LOGICAL_CLOCK
innodb-flush-log-at-timeout=1800

[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
```

On the other servers that host the API, the goal is for them to do select queries on the local slave server, and write changes back to the master which will allow us to have additional resources dedicated to receiving incoming API calls. Because they are primarily for Apache / PHP, I have reduced `innodb-buffer-pool-size = 64G`.

What optimizations should I use for Apache and PHP for high RAM servers?

I set this up, but not sure if I am under utilizing available resources:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             200
    MinSpareServers          20
    MaxSpareServers          50
    MaxRequestWorkers        100
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0    
        ServerLimit           512
        MaxClients            512
        MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

A more complete overview of my settings including variables, status, mysqltuner.pl report can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eeGHzFX95j5auJ5lTYum?p=catalogue

## Updates

We are receiving about 5600 requests per hour right now, about 70% may have up to 500 records per request that needs an update or insert query. That adds up to around 550 queries per second. Server load is commonly between 2.5-4.

The website was written in Laravel 5.4 and we tested throughput to the normal API routes using Laravel, Eloquent, and so on and when using Apache Benchmark using the following:    `ab  -c 100 -n 2000 -p sample.json -T application/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiO" https://www.myserver.com/api/accounting`

Here are the results:

```
Benchmarking www.myserver.com (be patient)
Completed 200 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 1200 requests
Completed 1400 requests
Completed 1600 requests
Completed 1800 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Finished 2000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.29
Server Hostname:        www.myserver.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1.2,ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,2048,256
TLS Server Name:        www.myserver.com

Document Path:          /api/accounting
Document Length:        65 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   375.487 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        1134
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 1134, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      735018 bytes
Total body sent:        162864000
HTML transferred:       131018 bytes
Requests per second:    5.33 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       18774.370 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       187.744 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.91 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        423.57 kb/s sent
                        425.49 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        3  315 1554.1      5   11497
Processing:  8420 18299 2501.9  18658   24051
Waiting:     8419 18298 2501.9  18658   24050
Total:       8424 18614 2791.2  18792   30388

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  18792
  66%  19699
  75%  20247
  80%  20619
  90%  21560
  95%  22343
  98%  23933
  99%  27099
 100%  30388 (longest request)
```

sample.json contained 500 records and we had the server load hit a load of 103. You will also notice we had over half our posts fail.

[image]

It seems apache is our bottleneck, and as I dug into it using `get_included_files()` I found that Laravel uses 275 includes just to get to the routes.php file, by the time it starts posting to our API, it uses 462, and by the end of posting to the API it uses 575 included files.

We rebuilt the same function outside Laravel using a single PHP page that defined the PDO connection, looped over the data queries in the same way generating queries for inserts and updates and it completed the same task with these stats:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   16.367 seconds
Complete requests:      2000
Failed requests:        228
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 228, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      502228 bytes
Total body sent:        162804000
HTML transferred:       126228 bytes
Requests per second:    122.19 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       818.366 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       8.184 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          29.97 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        9713.76 kb/s sent
                        9743.73 kb/s total

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        3    9  14.7      6      98
Processing:   242  800 281.3    764    2187
Waiting:      241  799 281.3    764    2187
Total:        246  809 283.8    774    2195

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    774
  66%    905
  75%    986
  80%   1040
  90%   1201
  95%   1328
  98%   1493
  99%   1618
 100%   2195 (longest request)
```

Server load only hit 12 while posting these with 0 failed posts. Because of the significant improvement, we are looking at pulling the API code out of Laraverl and optimizing one server for Mysql, and then having multiple slaves. Each slave would have read only access to localhost for the API to query to determine whether each record should be an update or insert statement, then would execute queries on the MySQL master.

While I have looked around for answers, so many resources were written when 4GB-32GB RAM was normal, and when you do find one with 512GB, it usually refers to an SSD.

Comment: Tuning almost always should include measuring/logging and then a bit of trial and error with some good testing.  The popular solution these days is to scaling out, not scaling to large 512GB systems.  So I suspect you may on your own a bit here.

Comment: @Zoredache I found these servers at a computer recycler (they get tens of thousands of servers per year as corporations upgrade) and got a killer deal on them ($1500 each). So while I realize we would normally put in more servers and scale laterally, I would love to know how to get the most out of these before I add on more.  Michael, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: You're pretty clearly CPU constrained here, which is common with PHP web apps and some other languages. You may have 512GB of RAM but you're using less than a tenth of that. So this server is way unbalanced for your workload. It's very likely you have to upgrade the CPUs. What processor(s) do you have now? What power management settings are set in the BIOS?

Comment: Thanks, the master has dual 6 core  E5-2667 v1 @2.9Ghz, the slaves have dual 4 core E5-2643 v2 @ 3.50GHz. I am using default settings in the BIOS

Comment: I should add that at this time we are a startup with only about 50 customers, we are envisioning having thousands but have waited to do any advertising or sales before we have things as optimized as they can be.

Comment: What OS and PHP version are you using? Have you configured and enabled opcache?

Comment: It is on Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.2 and yes, opcache is in use

Comment: Honestly, get the fastest and highest core count CPUs those servers will accept, and they will probably keep up. That's the E5-2697v2, which you can find for $275-$300 on eBay. So $1650-$1800 for six of them should put you right. If you're on a budget, resell the old processors to recover some of that expense.

Comment: @Alan Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry I didn't see your response sooner. Here is everything you asked for plus hdparm results for disk speed. http://plnkr.co/edit/eeGHzFX95j5auJ5lTYum?p=catalogue

Comment: Alan, Thanks for posting all the items requested.  Ulimit and 5 suggestions are available as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion for your ulimit -a results,

```
ulimit -n 24000    to enable more than current limit of 1024 Open Files
```

The above is dynamic with Linux OS.  Stop/Start services would have access to the handles.
To make this persistent across OS shutdown/restart, review this url for similar OS instructions.
These instructions set 500000 for the file-max, please set your capacity at 24000 for now.
ulimit please set to 24000, which will allow MySQL to use 10,000 requested 
and have spares for other apps

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section (RPS = Rate Per Second)

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=36G  # from 240G because your innodb data+ndx ~ 22G
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% cpu cycles used for this function
max_connections=600  # from 500 - you are denying many connections today
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of content of web site mentioned in my profile, Network profile.

Comment: Thank you Wilson, I will implement and do some benchmarks to compare

Answer (score 1):

Thundering herd.  Don't have such a high number of Apache children.  Set it no higher than, say, the number of cores (threads) in your cpu(s).  Keep in mind that MySQL is also competing for those cores.

You have conflicting values for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  Set it to perhaps twice the amount of data that you have, but not so big that it causes swapping.  And set `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16`.

Is the "500" requests in a *single* `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or IODKU?  If not, let's see what you are doing, and work toward making it a single SQL command.  This may speed up the MySQL part by a factor of 10.

Related to that is the question of who decides between "inserting" and "updating"?

What is the relevance of "JSON"?  Is there a big JSON string that splits into 500 inserts?  Or is a JSON string the 'meat' of the insert?

To get a better feel for the activity:  How many queries per second are you performaing?  How many rows are inserted (or updated) per second?